# I have a problem with the python terminal

Tags: terminal, built-in

When I try to use the help command with any module it gives me this message:
**C:\Users******\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe: can't open file 'e:\python\078 - Modules  Part 3  Install External Packages.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

I tried to search google and stack overflow for this problem but there was no help